# Request location with precise off as default

Tags: ios, core-location

My app doesn't need precise location, just a city is sufficient for it. When I request location authorization, how can I make `Precise: Off` by default?

I tried settings the design accuracy for `CLLocationManager` to `kCLLocationAccuracyReduced`, but it still asks with `Precise: On` by default. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10660/ explains it completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the key [`NSLocationDefaultAccuracyReduced`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nslocationdefaultaccuracyreduced) with a value of `true` in your `info.plist` file.  When you do this the user is prompted for their approximate location and no precise on/off pill is shown.

Note that this key shows as *Privacy - Location Default Accuracy Reduced* in Xcode's Plist editor

[image]