# How to access only generalise location in mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, location

I am developing react native mobile app where I am getting user's location, everything working well just one thing get confused me.

When default permission popup present it shows, 'Precise:On', where I want to get only generalise location.

So how I can disable from app that app only ask only generalise location.

I am using this code to get location in app

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      auth = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          message: 'This app needs access to your location',
          title: 'Location Permission',
          buttonPositive: '',
        },
      );
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      auth = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse');
    }
```

Or is there any default settings we have to change from device's settings.
Someone please help me.

Please check this screenshot, it shows 'Precise:On'

[image]

Comment: On iOS you need to specify `kCLLocationAccuracyReduced` for the `desiredAccuracy` property of your `CLLocationManager`.  Since you are using react you will need to investigate the package you are using for location to see if it can provide access to change that setting at the native layer.

Comment: Okay for iOS it helps me https://stackoverflow.com/a/65877196/5146494 Looking for android as well

Comment: try ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION instead of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  it gives you less accurate location and it more battery friendly and generally speaking be carefull of timeout it can sometimes provide undefined in some android devices